# Dimensions in QFT

Tags: field-theory, dimensional-analysis

In natural units ($\hbar = c = 1$), I have understood that the mass dimensions of the scalar field $[\phi] = 1$ using the fact that the action is dimensionless and the definition of the Lagrangian density for a scalar field.

However, do the dimensions of $\phi$ change when taking the adjoint? I cannot see any reason why they should.

For example, is it correct to say $(\phi \phi^{\dagger})^3$ in 4D has mass dimension $+6$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, $\phi$ and $\phi^\dagger$ have the same mass dimension.